# How to generate random array of ints using Stream API Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to generate random array of integers using new Stream API in Java 8. But I haven't understood this API clearly yet. So I need help. Here is my code.

```
Random random = new Random();
IntStream intStream = random.ints(low, high);
int[] array =  intStream.limit(limit) // Limit amount of elements
                                    .boxed() // cast to Integer
                                    .toArray();
```

But this code returns array of objects. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you want primitive `int` values, do not call [`IntStream::boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) as that produces [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects by [boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing).

Simply use [`Random::ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) which returns an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(size, lowBound, highBound).toArray();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the purpose of using boxed ?

Comment: @ketazafor: You'd only want to use `boxed()` if you did want an object array instead of an `int[]`.  That's your whole problem.

Comment: Thx for answer, one more question is there any elegant way to generate randow string using stream api ?

Comment: @ketazafor: depends on how your random `String` should be constructed. If it should interpret each random `int` as code point, combine the `int` stream of this answer with “[Simplest way to print an `IntStream` as a `String`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/2711488)”

Answer (score 7):

To generate random numbers from range 0 to 350, limiting the result to 10, and collect as a List. Later it could be typecasted.

However,  There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned.

```
List<Object> numbers =  new Random().ints(0,350).limit(10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and to get thearray of int use

```
int[] numbers =  new Random().ints(0,350).limit(10).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to streams, and .boxed() was what I was here looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to `boxed()`. Just receive the `Stream` as an `int[]`.

```
int[] array = intStream.limit(limit).toArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```java
ThreadLocalRandom     // A random number generator isolated to the current thread.
.current()            // Returns the current thread's `ThreadLocalRandom` object.
.ints( low , high )   // Pass the "origin" (inclusive) and "bound" (exclusive).
.limit( 100 )         // How many elements (integers) do you want in your stream?
.toArray()            // Convert the stream of `int` values into an array `int[]`.
```

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

You can do it using [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

The `ints` method generates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) within your specified bounds. Note the the low is *inclusive* while the high is *exclusive*. If you want to include your high number, just add one while calling the `ints` method.

```
int[] randInts = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( low , high ).limit(100).toArray();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/No5KE3).

Comment: No need for `.limit` call if you use the 3-argument version of [`Random.ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)). See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73032072/642706) on similar Question.