# How to read 50-100 arrays from file

Tags: java, file

My question is in the title. 
I'm really lazy to write 100-10000 numbers in one array, so I had an idea.

My code:

```
public class Generator(){
    Random random = new Random();
    try (FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter();//blah-blah, path to file
        int countOfArrays = random.nextInt(100)+50;
        int sizeOfArray = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countOfArrays; i++){
            sizeOfArray = random.nextInt(10000)+100;
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfArray; j++){
                    String s = Integer.valueOf(random.nextInt(100)).toString();
                    filewriter.write(s);
                }
                filewriter.append(/n);
        } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Can't generate arrays. Something went wrong);
      }
    }
```

How can I improve this code and how should I read from file properly? I think I need to create ArrayLists? I just dunno how to divide numbers.

Comment: Well, maybe if you added a space, or a comma, or whatever other separator between your numbers, it would be easier to read. Regarding reading files, do some research. For example, google for "Java IO tutorial", and read.

Comment: Java Stream allows you to generate a random integer stream quite easily. Check [How to generate random array of ints using Stream API Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793098/how-to-generate-random-array-of-ints-using-stream-api-java-8)

Answer (score 0):

you can read your file with a FileReader object or with a BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(theFile.getInputStream())) line by line.
You may also process each line(e.g. splitting by a whitespace or other separator) and rebuild the arrays.

Other improvements require a better description of the project.