# How should I generate a list of random numbers and determine the largest without using an array?

Tags: java, random

How do I generate a list of 5 random numbers between 10 and 100 in Java and  print the biggest random number without using an array?

```
public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println((int)((Math.random() * 91) + 10));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably possible to model this with a single random variable using a different distribution (100 has a 1/90 chance being the result, while 10 has a 1/90^5 chance, with the values in between becoming more probably as they approach the maximum). The folks on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help with that, if you're morbidly curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got the "Generate random int's" bit covered.  Now what you need is the "max of those without an array" bit.

Since you cannot store them in an array, you can still use a temp variable

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
  int tempMax = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ...
```

Using that, we can hold a value outside of our loop.  Now we need to compare our temp value with what we've generated, to see if we've generated a larger value.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  int newValue = (int)((Math.random() * 91) + 10);

  if (newValue > tempMax) {
    // code goes here
  }
```

Note: it's important that `tempMax` starts out with a smaller value than what you can generate (10 in this case).  Otherwise, you may generate a string of `-1`'s and your max will report back as 0.

After that, it's just a simple assignment

```java
if (newValue > tempMax) {
  tempMax = newValue;
}
```

Altogether

```java
class Random {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int tempMax = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      int newValue = (int)((Math.random() * 91) + 10);

      if (newValue > tempMax) {
        tempMax = newValue;
      }
    }

    int max = tempMax;

    System.out.println("Max value" + max);
  }
}
```

---

This looks like homework to me, so I've tried to lay out the thinking process behind how to do this.  Still, learning to search Google (and find documents at your skill level) is an important skill, since questions like these are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
int maxRand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(5, 10, 101).max().getAsInt();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25793098/113632) covers the gist, but we call [`.max().getAsInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max--) instead. It's safe to call `.getAsInt()` since we know the stream is non-empty, and therefore there will be a maximum value.

You can also use `new Random()`, as the linked answer suggests, but I'd default to `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` unless you have a good reason to manually construct `Random` instances.