# How to generate a list of N random integers in a range using Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can we generate a list of 30 random integers in range (for example `[101, 299]`) with Java 8 stream?

Basically I don't want to iterate through a loop 30 times to generate and want to use Java stream api to accomplish this.

Comment: Basically, you just need to browse the relevant javadocs and the information you need to work it out is all there.

Comment: As @StephenC already mentioned , Java docs are powerful . I think that what you are looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( 30L , 101 , 300 ).toArray();
```

## Details

Use [`IntStream.generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate(java.util.function.IntSupplier)).

```java
IntStream stream = IntStream.generate( ( ) -> { return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 101 , 300 ); } ); // ( inclusive , exclusive )
stream.limit( 30 ).forEach( System.out :: println );
```

We can combine those lines, and collect into an array.

```java
int[] randomIntegers =
        IntStream
                .generate( ( ) -> { return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 101 , 300 ); } )
                .limit( 30 )
                .toArray();
```

And we can further abbreviate by calling the convenience method [`Random.ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(long,int,int)).

```
int[] randomIntegers = 
        ThreadLocalRandom
        .current()
        .ints( 30L, 101 , 300 ) 
        .toArray();
```