# How to convert Stream of Characters into a String in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to convert `Stream<Character>` into a `String` in Java 8? `Collectors.joining()` expects `CharSequence` hence it is giving compilation error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20266422/2541573

Comment: I'm not really sure why this question was closed. It poses a single question (how to convert `Stream<Character>` to `String`), and also states why one seemingly obvious solution does not work. How can this question be more focused?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Refer to @jubobs solution link. That is, you could do it this way in your case:

```
Stream<Character> testStream = Stream.of('a', 'b', 'c');

String result = testStream.collect(Collector.of(
    StringBuilder::new,
    StringBuilder::append,
    StringBuilder::append,
    StringBuilder::toString));
```

This is more performant then `map/cast`ping each character to a `String` first and then `joining`, as `StringBuilder#append(char c)` will cut out that intermediate step.

Comment: Does not work for `"abc".chars()`, which is an IntStream. There, one has to use  `.collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/873282

Comment: AFAICT the first `StringBuilder::append` reference is calling `StringBuilder.append(Object)` which will call `toString()` on each character, impacting performance. This will ensure the correct `append` method is being called: `.collect(StringBuilder::new, (builder, c) -> builder.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)`

Comment: this collect does not work with IntStream, but it does with Stream. you can use .boxed() for making that change

Comment: I can't believe that this is not part of the standard API by now.

Comment: What's the actual meaning of the word `performant`? I couldn't find the word on my dictionary. :)

Answer (score 14):

Convert `Character` to `String`

```
Stream<Character> st = Stream.of('C','h','t');
String result = st.map(c->c.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);  //Cht
```

Or by using method reference

```
st.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining())
```

And `Collectors.joining` internally uses `StringBuilder` [here](http://Collectors.joining)

Or just by using `forEach`

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    Stream<Character> st = Stream.of('C','h','t');

    st.forEach(ch->builder.append(ch));
```

Comment: or `.map(Character::toString)`, but this is less effective than a `StringBuilder::append`

Comment: `...map(Object::toString)....` should work

Comment: `Collectors.joining` uses `StringBuilder` internally, but that doesn’t change the fact the appending `Character` elements via `StringBuilder.append(char)` is more efficient than converting each of them to a `String` first before doing `StringBuilder.append(String)`. But since these are all strings with length one, the per-element costs are not catastrophic.