# Java Cannot convert from String to Int

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Hi i'm just trying to have a one-liner that lowercase every characters of a string :

```
String sum = "HI THERE";
sum.chars().map(x -> Integer.toString(x).toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

And my compiler is answering : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int"
I'm not sure why ? (chars() is returning an IntStream and x is an Integer ...)

Comment: Why not just use `sum = sum.toLowerCase();`?

Comment: Agree with the above comment. But specifically regarding your error, `chars()` returns an `IntStream`, and its `map` method expects an `int -> int` function. You'd need to use `mapToObj`.

Comment: Yes i know i can just `sum=sum.toLowerCase();` but it was just a pretext to mess with streams and lambas (to have a better graps on them).
And thx i know have a nice line : `sum.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)Character.toLowerCase(c)).forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: 1) `Integer.toString(x)` returns the string representation of the integer value, e.g. `"65"` instead of `"A"`. 2) To get from an `IntStream` to a `Stream` of objects, you have to use `mapToObj` instead of `map`. But you probably want to stay with an `IntStream` for efficiency, i.e. `sum.chars().map( Character::toLowerCase)`, then 3) see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/2711488). But if you just want to print them, `sum.chars().map(Character::toLowerCase).forEachOrdered(c -> System.out.println( (char)c));` would do.