# How to remove duplicate characters from each string in a list of strings using the Java streams API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert `List<String> = ["SSSttttrrrriiiiinnnggg","vvvvvooootttteee","mmmmaaaaddddaaaammm"]` to `List<String> =["String","eotv","dam"]` using the streams API in Java?

I am able to eliminate duplicates in the string using the below code but I am not sure how to handle a list of strings.  Order is not important and also must not be present in the output if the letter is repeated multiple times.

```java
String string = "SSSttttrrriiiinnnnnggg";

string.chars()
.mapToObj(item -> (char) item)
.collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: What happens if we have such string - `ttteeesssttt`? Should this result in `test` or `tes`?

Comment: Yes, tes must be in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`IntStream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct()) for only getting distinct characters:

```java
string
  .codePoints()//all code points (~chars)
  .distinct()//only distinct code points
  .collect(StringBuilder::new,
           StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
           StringBuilder::append)//convert back to string
  .toString();
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/10871900) for converting between `IntStream`s of [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) and strings.

You can then wrap this in another `Stream:`

```java
list
.stream()
.map(string->
  string
  .codePoints()
  .distinct()
  .collect(StringBuilder::new,
           StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
           StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();
).toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream#map` to transform each element of a `Stream`. `.distinct` can be used to remove duplicates, keeping only one copy of each unique character.

```java
var res = strs.stream().map(s -> s.chars().distinct()
              .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
              .collect(Collectors.joining())).toList();
```

Comment: By using s.chars() directly we might get compile time issues  as s is inferred as object type just by typecasting to string will resolve this thanks for the answer .

var res = strs.stream().map(
s -> s.toString().chars().distinct()
                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())).toList();

Comment: @abhiAbhinav That can't happen unless your `List` is declared incorrectly. You can see that it works fine [here](https://tio.run/##bZC/TsQwDMbn61NYnRKJywsUWFhBN5QNMfjSXEnJnypxKyF0z15s9SQG@C1Wvi/O53jCFY/T8LltPs65EEwsmIV8MM@@Utf8kSsVh9E85RCcpVxq1zTzcg7egg1YK7ygT/DdHG5iJSQua/YDRLZUT8Wn8e0dsIxVy82DRN3v@iM3lAoPIJrJF9X2fU9MYbyQUhrHsb2DdhUyI75zTrTIIDMwUvnY6o4zVixQnLwsAbdvKG0izqrCkXON/cBSWRo42idLu/uaT@dJWbmyj2hWDIs7XZSSBg1Wa35fMHbfivrdjpmyT9yktNb/2ZTlo@zKjP1XJRdNXsjMnEQhKR5ZrGtz3bYf).

Comment: Yes , you are right my List had no type to infer that caused this compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map()` method of the `stream` class to compress each string in the list and then gather the result back into a list using the collect() method.

Here is how you can do it:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("SSSttttrrrriiiiinnnggg","vvvvvooootttteee","mmmmaaaaddddaaaammm");

List<String> compressedList = list.stream()
        .map(s -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char prev = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                if (c != prev) {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        sb.append(count);
                    }
                    prev = c;
                    count = 1;
                    sb.append(c);
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            sb.append(count);
            return sb.toString();
        })
        .map(s -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(compressedList);
```

This code first compresses each string using a `StringBuilder` to keep track of the character and count and then uses another `StringBuilder` to remove all non-lowercase characters. The final outcome is compiled into a list and printed. The result will be:

```
[String, eotv, dam]
```