# Problem while using Collectors.joining() in Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I tried to filter a stream of characters based on some constraints and then tried to collect them in a string.

This is what I tried:

```
String s = str.chars()
          .mapToObj(c -> (char) c) 
          .map(Character::toLowerCase)
          .filter(c -> !Character.isWhitespace(c))
          .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

`Collectors.joining()` should concatenate the contents of the stream into a String, but this last bit of code produces an error. Why is this happening?

Comment: Add another mapping to convert the character to string before joining.

Comment: `Collectors.joining()` is for a stream of strings, not a stream of Characters.

Comment: Likely to do with the fact that you're working with `Character`. A lazy solution would be `.map(c -> "" + c)` right before the `#collect`.

Comment: Get familiar with the concept of *codepoints*. Not only are they necessary for handling characters outside the BMP, dropping the idea that you need a `char` avoids the boxing overhead of your approach, `str.codePoints() .filter(c -> !Character.isWhitespace(c)) .map(Character::toLowerCase) .mapToObj(Character::toString) .collect(Collectors.joining());` Note how most operations happily operate on `int` now instead of `Character` objects. Further, since `toLowerCase` does not affect the outcome of `isWhitespace`, it’s more efficient to filter first.

Comment: You could even avoid the creation of temporary `String` objects for collecting, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20268845/2711488).

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the suggestion. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the Character to String before joining, you need this:

```
...
.map(c -> Character.toString(c))
.collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: I don't think that's the same. More something like `str = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "");` because of the whitespaces.

Comment: @maraca I removed my suggest, It was not correct :)

Answer (score 1):

your input stream at Collectors.joining is `Stream<Character>`, wouldn't work with Collectors.joining, you have to convert the Character to string first

do

```
 String s = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
    .map(Character::toLowerCase)
    .filter(c -> !Character.isWhitespace(c))
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @amycodes I think a simple debug on any available IDE could verify you the validity of the above codes. Unless you're a bot or something then I'm just chatting with air

Comment: It was a pre written response but I am a human lol. The point of the response is to highlight that you should add relevant documentation links etc for future readers to refer to.